# Automated Installation of Configuration Profile

Tags: iphone, configuration, profile

We would like to allow our iPhone application users to access to our secure and protected Wi-Fi hotspots, without having to manually download a configuration profile themselves.    From my experience today, users have to either open an email with a profile attached, click on a link or have the app programmatically open up safari in order to download a configuration profile.  We’d like to avoid the users having to do anything at all.

To that end, does anyone know if it is possible to have a configuration profile installed automatically on a user’s iPhone, such as when the mobile application is downloaded from the app store?  Or is there another mechanism through which we could allow our iPhone users to gain access to our secure Wi-Fi hotspots.

Also, I am curious does anyone know of any companies that have enabled such a solution?

(note there is an older thread on this topic from 2010, which implies that this is not possible.  Given it has now been 3 years and that we're on  ios 7, I would like to see if the capabilities of iOS has changed.)

Answer (score 0):

> There are four ways to deploy configuration profiles:
>
> 1. By physically connecting the device
> 2. In an email message
> 3. On a webpage
> 4. Using over-the air configuration

[More on this Document.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html)